# Illustrator: cut and paste preserving groups

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, image-editing

I probably know already the answer but maybe I am wrong.

I want to copy and paste or cut and paste part of drawing while preserving groups.

I have 2 vector drawings in one file which objects share groups. I can select one of drawing, let's say right drawing with group selection tool and Illustrator only selects objects of this particular drawing (otherwise it just select both drawings).

But after copy/paste or cut/paste into the same or different file it destroys groups structure and all objects of drawing are placed as ungrouped bunch of objects.

The only workaround I have found till now is to create copy of file, then in second file remove left drawing and copy right drawing into the first file (where right drawing were already removed). This operation gives me copy of groups - the outcome I wanted from the start.

Is it the only solution or maybe AI is a little smarter in that field?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This would depend on how the file is constructed. I don't think there's a way to answer your question without access to the original file unfortunately.  Illustrator documents can have nested groups, and multiple layers, all of which could potentially cause problems, but that's only a guess.  Maybe a fix would be to ungroup everything several times until there are no groups left, then regroup each drawing separately.

Comment: Illustrator *does* preserve groups upon selecting, copy and pasting. So... there's some *other* issue going on here. Perhaps a clipping mask or other construction.

Comment: Its SVG. It was created with import from DWG illustrator feature. It has one layer, and 10-15 main groups. There are no subgroups. As i said, two drawings share groups so normal selection is not possible (left and right drawing is selected then) and working with isolation groups is too much pain in a. So i choose right or left drawing with CTRL key or using group selection user. If I put it in this file all pasted objects are no longer grouped as lousy paths. They have proper appearance like before. If I put copied objects in to new file i get the same result - lousy paths.

Comment: So only duplication of svg file is a workaround for me now.